# Why FPS (frames per second) dropped after I added a 30ms delay between frames sending to client using RTC in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, webrtc, frame-rate, live-streaming

I modified the below code to the code just below it to send frames after 30ms delay to get better FPS but to my surprise they dropped drastically instead of going up, earlier I was receiving 22 fps after modification I got just 2 fps

Before:

```
def _producer(self):
    old_frame = None
    self._setReady(True)
    while not self._shouldClose:
        if not context.context_dict[context.rtc_connections]:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        frame_to_send = context.context_dict[context.currentFrame]
        if old_frame is None:
            self._put_nowait(frame_to_send)
        else:
            is_similar = old_frame == frame_to_send
            if isinstance(is_similar, np.ndarray):
                is_similar = is_similar.all()

            if not is_similar:
                self._put_nowait(frame_to_send)

        if frame_to_send is not None:
            old_frame = frame_to_send

    self._setReady(False)
    self._log.info("Ended camera capture")
```

After:

```
def _producer(self):
    self._setReady(True)
    last_frame_time = None

    while not self._shouldClose:
        if not context.context_dict[context.rtc_connections]:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue

        if last_frame_time is None:
            last_frame_time = time.time()
            frame_to_send = context.context_dict[context.currentFrame]
            self._put_nowait(frame_to_send)

        current_frame_time = time.time()

        if round(current_frame_time - last_frame_time, 2) < 0.03:
            continue

        last_frame_time = current_frame_time

        frame_to_send = context.context_dict[context.currentFrame]

        if frame_to_send is not None:
            self._put_nowait(frame_to_send)

    self._setReady(False)
    self._log.info("Ended camera capture")
```

Comment: There's no question in above text, just FYI. You may want to be specific on both why you tried that and what you want to know about its behaviour.

Comment: @diggusbickus in ideal scenario we should be getting 25 fps, but the earlier code (with no modification) through put 22 fps as some processing is done which takes more than 30ms for sure. What we wanted to check was how much fps are increased after we remove all processing and just through puts fps with 30ms delay which for sure can through put 25fps but to our surprise instead of increasing they went down to 2.

Comment: I have reduced computing basically by just sending the frame as it is, earlier code does some processing on each frame before passing in to the client the later code just passes the frame ensuring a 30ms delay between each frame, also _put_nowait is always executed once, as "last_frame_time = None" only for the first iteration. @diggusbickus